# pushing data to embedded array error nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm using mongoose, and I'm getting an error while trying to push some data into an embedded array for one of my already established documents. My app is basically like a forum where a user post a topic question, someone can answer it, and then someone can post a comment on that answer. The problem is that, I've set up my database so that the topics and answers are referenced to one another in separate models, but the comments are embedded within the answer schema. With every method I try I get an error saying either:

```
message: 'The field \'comment\' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId(\'5669acad9b68142c1258b472\')}', 
driver: true, 
index: 0, 
code: 16837, 
errmsg: 'The field \'comment\' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId(\'5669acad9b68142c1258b472\')}' }
```

or:

```
{ [ValidationError: Answer validation failed]
message: 'Answer validation failed',
name: 'ValidationError',
errors:
{ 'comment.1._id':
  { [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "[object Object]" at path
"_id"]
    message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_
id"',
    name: 'CastError',
    kind: 'ObjectID',
    value: [Object],
    path: '_id',
    reason: undefined } } }
```

Answer.js: model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var AnswerSchema = new Schema(
{
  _topic: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Topic'},
  _user: {type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'User'},
  likes: Number,
  dislikes: Number,
  content: String,
  created_at: {type: Date, default: new Date},
  comment: [{
              _user: {type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'User'},
              content: String
            }]

});

var Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
```

topics.js: controller

```
add_comment: function(req,res)
  {
    Answer.findOne({_id: req.body.answerid}, function(err, answer)
    {      
      if(err)
      {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else
      {
        console.log(answer);
        answer.comment.push([{_user: req.body.currentUser, content: req.body.content}]);
        answer.save(function(err)
        {
          if(err)
          {
            console.log(err);
          }
          else
          {
           res.redirect('/'); 
          }
        })
      }
   })
  }
```

if i simply update the data (to replace other comments) it will process it with no err, if I use an operator like $push I'll receive the same errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: answer.comment is an array why you push another array [{_user: req.body.currentUser, content: req.body.content}] onto it ? Should be         answer.comment.push({_user: req.body.currentUser, content: req.body.content});

Comment: that's what I did first, but then it threw me an err saying that I must push an array into comment.